# Scalable seeding for Sequelize with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js, seed, seeding

I want to set up a piece of code that resets my whole database and seeds everything.

The problem is that with a few Foreign Key constraints, the seeds need to happen in order, however those seeds that are not dependent should happen at the same time asynchronously.

How can I define these seeds in separate files properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes down to exporting Promises with `module.exports`.

When I was requiring a file that returned a Promise directly, the Promise was immediately called.
I solved the problem by returning functions that return the Promise.

`Resetting DB and seeding`

```js
const Seed = require('../seeds/index');

sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
    return Seed();
}).then(() => {
    // DB reset
}).catch(err => {
    // Error in one of the seeds, specific error in 'err'
});
```

`seeds/index.js` - Calling the seeds in other files

```js
const UserSeed = require('./user');
const BComponentSeed = require('./bcomponent');
const MaterialSeed = require('./material');

module.exports = function() {
    return Promise.all([ // Returning and thus passing a Promise here
        // Independent seeds first
        UserSeed(),
        BComponentSeed(),
        MaterialSeed(),
    ]).then(() => {
        // More seeds that require IDs from the seeds above
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('********** Successfully seeded db **********');
    });
}
```

`seeds/user.js` - Example of the User seed

```js
const User = require('../models/user');
const crypto = require('../globs/crypto');

module.exports = function() {
    return User.bulkCreate([ // Returning and thus passing a Promise here
        {
            email: 'John@doe.com',
            password: crypto.generateHash('john'),
        },
        {
            email: 'a@a.com',
            password: crypto.generateHash('a'),
        },
    ]);
};
```

Came up with this while responding to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4987)